# Problem with subfigure numbering when using the memoir class

Tags: numbering, memoir, subfloats, counters

I'm using the `memoir` class for my thesis and I noticed it recently started giving the wrong numbering for subfigures. I have some old PDFs when it was working properly and I'm quite sure I haven't messed with these figures in a while, so I'm not sure what the problem is. I have a MWE below.

```
\documentclass[brazilian,a4paper,12pt,oneside,openleft]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx} %package to manage images
\newsubfloat{figure}% Allow subfloats in figure environment

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter to have proper numbering}

\begin{figure}[!hptb]
            \centering 
            \subbottom[]{          
                \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}          
                \label{sf:a} %Nome da sub-Fig. para referenciá-la diretamente como 1a.
            } 
            \hfill
            \subbottom[]{   
                \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}
                \label{sf:b}
            }   
                    
            \caption{\subcaptionref{sf:a} Subfig a \subcaptionref{sf:b} Subfig b}
            \label{fig:ab}  
\end{figure}

Some sample text referencing Fig.~\ref{fig:ab} which contains both Fig.~\ref{sf:a} and Fig.~\ref{sf:b}.

\end{document}
```

Which gives output similar to the Figure attached at the end of the question. As you can see, the subfigure labels in the caption show up as `()` and `(a)` rather than `(a)` and `(b)`. I guess some counter is not incrementing properly, but I have no idea which one it is. The `(a)` and `(b)` labels show up properly in the actual figure too, which adds to my confusion.

Lastly, I noticed in this MWE, when I call `\ref{sf:a}` and `\ref{sf:b}` I get only a `1` rather than `1.1(a)` or `1.1(b)`. This has even more confused, as on my thesis, using similar commands I get the equivalent of `1.1(a)`, which is my intended effect! So it's nice that it's working properly on my thesis, but I don't know why it's not working properly in the MWE.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Output from MWE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the correct output, place the `\label` inside of the optional argument of `\subbottom` as shown in the following example:

```
\documentclass[brazilian,a4paper,12pt,oneside,openleft]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx} %package to manage images
\newsubfloat{figure}% Allow subfloats in figure environment

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter to have proper numbering}

\begin{figure}[!hptb]
            \centering 
            \subbottom[\label{sf:a}]{          
                \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}          
                 %Nome da sub-Fig. para referenciá-la diretamente como 1a.
            } 
            \hfill
            \subbottom[\label{sf:b}]{   
                \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}
                
            }   
                    
            \caption{\subcaptionref{sf:a} Subfig a \subcaptionref{sf:b} Subfig b}
            \label{fig:ab}  
\end{figure}

Some sample text referencing Fig.~\ref{fig:ab} which contains both Fig.~\ref{sf:a} and Fig.~\ref{sf:b}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solved it, thanks!

Is this something that was recently changed? I still have my old pdfs when doing it the way I showed it worked properly... But alas, I guess it doesn't matter. I'll fix up my figures with your suggestion. Once again, thanks!

Comment: @Deaga  The typo in the  of where `\label` had to be placed was changed i march 2020 and `\subbottom` was changed in November 2019 in order to get better hyperref anchor placements