# memoir class manual bug : where to include label in subfigure

Tags: captions, memoir, subfloats

This is a bug report to the documentation of the memoir class. A Q&A site seems to me like a odd place to report this, but it's what the "Remarks to the user" section of the manual suggest, so I hope I'm doing it right.

---

I'm using the memoir class and its subfloats to create subfigures.

With memoir version 3.7h the label could be defined within the `text` argument of `subbottom` as it appears on its manual (example of figure 10.19 of the memoir class manual). Like so:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}

Figure \ref{fig:twosubfig} has two subfigures,
namely \subcaptionref{sf:1} and \subcaptionref{sf:2}.

\begin{figure}
\subbottom[Subfigure 1]{\fbox{SUBFIGURE ONE}\label{sf:1}}
\hfill
\subbottom[Subfigure 2]{\fbox{SUBFIGURE TWO}\label{sf:2}}
\caption{Figure with two subfigures} \label{fig:twosubfig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

With generates the text:

> Figure 0.1 has two subfigures, namely () and (a).

However, with memoir version 3.7j, the same code generates the caption:

> Figure 0.1 has two subfigures, namely 0.1(a) and (b).

The issue can be seen on the manual itself. The sentence right before the example differs between the manual for version 3.7j and 3.7h.

Rereading the manual, I see the following on the manual (emphasis mine):

> A `\label` command **may** be included in the `{subtitle}` argument of the subcaptioning commands.

So I guess one should have been defining the label in the `{subtitle}` argument instead of `{text}`.

Two issues then:

1. the example code on the memoir manual for figure 10.19 should be changed to define the label inside the `{subtitle}` (which will also fix the incorrect text, which currently reads "Figure 10.19 has two subfigures, namely 10.19() and (a).")
2. Instead of "A `\label` command **may**..." maybe use "A `\label` command **must**..." or "If a `\label` command is used, it **must**..."

Comment: Latest version of [`memoir`](//ctan.org/pkg/memoir) (3.7n) produces the same output.

Comment: I have version 3.7n of the `memoir` user guide, dated 2020/10/04. On p. 201, it says "Figure 10.19 has two subfigures, namely 10.19(a) and (b)." The first issue you've identified thus appears to have already been fixed in the meantime.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565677/problem-with-subfigure-numbering-when-using-the-memoir-class which contains a statement about this from the `memoir` maintainer

Comment: BTW the manual also states my email.

Comment: @daleif yes, but it suggests one should prefer stackexchange. I don't mind, it just felt weird. I hope I did it right.

Comment: Why, a lot of people here knows a lot about memoir